# Reflected triangle of asterisks using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I've seen posts about this same problem, but I need to create the same triangle, only reflected. For example, if my recursive method `rightTriangle` calls `rightTriangle(4)`, the output should look something this:

[image]

Here is the working code that makes the right triangle of asterisks, but is reflected:

```
public static String rightTriangle(int n){
    if( n <= 0 ){
        return " ";
    } 

    String line = rightTriangle(n - 1);
    line = line + "*";
    System.out.println(line);

    return line;
}
```

The output for `rightTriangle(4)` is correct, with the exception that the triangle of asterisks prints out vertically reflected as opposed to the image above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Try not to include a link to the image and paste the text for the desired outputs in preformatted text like what you did with the code in case the images disappear or get removed in the future.

Comment: You don't need recursion.
1st line   = n-1 spaces 1 *  ;
2nd line = n-2 spaces 2 *  ;
......
nth line = n * ;
Try identifying patterns.

Answer (score 1):

A prefix of spaces might be needed to be passed as an argument to the recursive method:

```java
public static void rightTriangle(int n) {
    rightTriangle(n, "");
}

public static String rightTriangle(int n, String prefix) {
    if( n <= 0 ) {
        return "";
    } 

    String line = rightTriangle(n - 1, prefix + " ") + "*";

    System.out.println(prefix + line);

    return line; // only asterisks
}
```

Output for `rightTriangle(4)`:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

---

**Update**

A "single-method" version may look like this:

```java
static int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public static String rightTriangle(int n) {
    if( n <= 0 ) {
        return "";
    }
    
    max = Math.max(max, n);

    String line = rightTriangle(n - 1) + "*";

    System.out.println(" ".repeat(max -(n - 1)) + line);

    return line;
}
```

Output for `rightTriangle(5)`

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with only one method?

Comment: Some accumulator for a prefix is needed to implement proper padding with spaces.  Single method is possible but with a sort of "cheat-codes": 1) use `String::repeat` to calculate the prefix; 2) store the max value of `n` outside the method

Comment: Technically, an additional method seems to be needed here anyway to properly initialize `max` bnetween two invocations

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    rightTriangle(4, 1, 1);      
}    

public static void rightTriangle(int totalLines, int currentLine, int n) {
    if (currentLine <= totalLines) {
      if (n <= (totalLines - currentLine)) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      else {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      if (n < totalLines) {
        rightTriangle(totalLines, currentLine, n+1);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println();
        rightTriangle(totalLines, currentLine+1, 1);
      }
    }
}
```

Calling it with:

```
rightTriangle(10, 1, 1);
```

Produces:

```
         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```